# Why doesn't Pages have printer paper size setting and it doesn't honor my default paper size setting too?

Tags: pages, printing

Pages doesn't have printer paper size setting.

[image: page print setting]

It doesn't honor my default paper size setting too. My default paper size is A4.

[image: A4]

But it seems that Pages still uses "US letter" as the paper size so the printer always got stuck and shows me a warning to change paper.

Now as a workaround I have to let Pages export the document as pdf formant then print the pdf. The printer dialog in preview has paper size setting and it honors my default paper size setting too.

How do I fix that ?

I am using MacOS 13.3.1 and Pages version 13.0 (7036.0.126) (I think it is the latest version)

--- update ---

I tried what the answer told me, reset Preset Menu to default setting after printing but it didn't fix my problem.

The print dialog still doesn't have the paper size setting and printing is still stuck.

[image: reset Preset menu]

Answer (score 2):

So in Pages you can check the presets:

[image]

Then in System Preferences you can set the settings based on your printer - Mac sets the printer up in the system so ALL programs use the standard...

[image]

Comment: Hi please see my update, reset to "Default setting" didn't fix my problem.